# How to force to lose focus of all fields in a form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lost-focus

When a input field changes (onchange) I trigger a function to set a variable. The only problem is that the field first has to lose focus before the variable is set and I can check if the field(s) is changed, this is what I want to do when the user clicks on a tab so I can check if the user is forgotten to submit his form in the previous tab. Ho to force lose focus of all possible fields, so first the `onchange` event can take place?

Comment: `document.body.focus()`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$(':focus').blur()
```

If you don't have jQuery in your site, you can replace it by :

```
let el = document.querySelector( ':focus' );
if( el ) el.blur();
```

Comment: nice and easy, love it

Comment: Could someone please provide an non-jquery answer?

Comment: @posfan12 Edited with a non-jquery version.

Comment: or as a safe one-liner: `document.querySelectorAll(':focus').forEach(el => el.blur());`

Comment: `querySelectorAll`? Is it possible for more than one element to have the focus?

Answer (score 18):

You don't need jQuery for this; vanillaJS can do this, too.

`document.activeElement.blur();`

Note: Usually, I would check for null-ness before calling a method, but [`activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) will only ever return null if there is no `‹body›` node, so this direct call is pretty safe.

Answer (score 4):

You can trigger a `.blur()` event

```
$('SomeElement').blur(function () {
   // do whatever
});

$('SomeElement').blur();
```

Comment: $('*:focus').blur() bacause texteraes and contentEditable elements can be focused too...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':focus').blur();
```

You can use this line of code and everything loses focus (jQuery)